Track the connection history to a certain table in SQL Server
Is there a way to keep the connection history to a certain table in SQL-server?
Not just the database because that's easy using the DMV's but just one particular table.

What do you want to track?  Types of commands, connection information? Usage of a table at all?

To expand on what Andrey said, there's no such thing as "connection to a table". A table is queried. It sounds like you want to track who queries a table?...if so what information do you want to know for which types (all?) of queries?

We are looking for the connection information for who or what app queries the table (so servernames, when queried, usernames,,...). And for all types of queries.

If you're running Enterprise Edition, you can use SQL Server Audit to audit the SELECT statements against a specific table.
If you don't have Enterprise Edition, you can look at using Extended Events instead and track the following events:

exec_prepared_sql
sql_statement_starting
sp_statement_starting
rpc_starting
sql_batch_starting

You can then filter on the sql_text field for your chosen table name.
